# Cannot parse Sub second time with Fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I've tried parse sub second time with fluentd  in_tail plugin on v0.14.14.
I expect this.

```
2017-04-13T08:20:24.369011+09:00    log.error.bar   
{"pid":"1","message":"exception instance is nil"}
2017-04-13T08:20:30.428146+09:00    log.error.bar   
{"pid":"1","message":"exception instance is nil"}
```

But fluentd couldn't capture it like this.

#### fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  type tail
  format multiline
  format_firstline /^time:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{6}$/
  format1  /^time:(?<time>.*)\n/
  format2  /pid:(?<pid>.*)\n/
  format3  /message:(?<message>.*)$/
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
  path /Users/foo/work/bar/log/error.log
  pos_file /tmp/hoge.pos
  tag log.error.bar
  read_from_head true
</source>

<match log.error.bar>
  type file
  path /Users/foo/work/fluent/log/bar/error/test.log
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L
</match>
```

#### test.log

```
time:2017-04-13 07:20:24.369011
pid:1
message:exception instance is nil

time:2017-04-13 07:20:30.428146
pid:1
message:exception instance is nil
```

then this is captured with fluend.
there is no sub sec information each line...

```
2017-04-13T08:20:24+09:00   log.error.bar   {"pid":"1","message":"exception instance is nil"}
2017-04-13T08:20:30+09:00   log.error.bar   {"pid":"1","message":"exception instance is nil"}
```

What is wrong on the code?
Could you teach me how to capture sub time with fluentd in_tail?